# bootstrap 3: drowdown-menu width like input-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I would like get my drowdown-menu as wide as my input-group. What is missing in the UL or LI part?

Here my example:
http://www.bootply.com/qmhyVLJ3y6

Thanks

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I solved this now by jQuery:

```
$( "#set_width_menu" ).width( $( "#get_width_menu" ).width() );
```

Thanks

Michael